# Arquivo de config Serilog sink asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou utilizando a biblioteca de log Serilog em `ASP.NET Core 2.1`

Estou usando com base no manual do Serilog disposto em: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

Normalmente o arquivo de configuração é no appsettings.json, **porém preciso pegar  a ConnectionString de outro local.** Então tentei fazer uma mescla entre appsettings.json e configurações, mas infelizmente não funcionou (ai ele nem cria a tabela) veja como está: 
(OBS: Essa config, é descrita no link acima)

```
var logDB = "Aqui minha connection string";
            var logTable = "LogError";
            var options = new ColumnOptions();
            options.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
            options.LogEvent.DataLength = 2048;
            options.PrimaryKey = options.TimeStamp;
            options.TimeStamp.NonClusteredIndex = true;



Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Warning()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer( 
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information,
                    connectionString: logDB,
                    tableName: logTable,
                    columnOptions: options)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("SetorErro", Common.SetorLogErro.MVC)
                .CreateLogger();
```

No código acima também já tentei colocar além dos parâmetros via C#, as config pelo appsettings.json

```
, appConfiguration: Configuration)
```

No meu arquivo appsettings, já tentei remover para não constar duplicado como deixar também as config, mesmo setando em cima, e não funciona, só funciona via appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=xxx.yyy.zzz",
          "tableName": "LogError",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information ", //https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "customColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "SetorErro",
                "DataType": "int",
                "AllowNull": true
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "LocalErro",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 150,
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Unico modo que funciona é quando faço o .ReadFrom

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
             .CreateLogger();
```

**Resumo:**

> Preciso pegar parte das configurações via appsettings.json e parde via
>   hard code.
>   Abri uma issue no projeto
>   https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/185

Comment: Você precisa trazer a connectionString via código? ou quer utilizar duas connectionStrings dentro do appSettings.json? não ficou claro na pergunta

Comment: obrigado por avisar, editei para ficar mais claro, preciso pegar a connection string e alguns parametros via código C# e outras config via appsettings.json, mas descobri que no asp.net core não funciona quase nda via código.

Comment: sim, provavelmente a melhor abordagem é utilizar o appsettings mesmo, o que acontece é que se vc mesclar hard code com o appsettings a biblioteca do serilog pira

Comment: @JulioBorges mas no help do serilog eles avisam que pode, e outro detalhe, via hardcode não funciona nda... parece ser um bug da biblioteca para asp.net core

Comment: sim, verdade. Você tentou remover as configurações do appSettings e colocar somente a configuração hard coded?

Comment: @JulioBorges sim, mas não funciona só hardcode abri um issue